# How to search and find all the files with particular name using batch?

Tags: batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

I am running a following command,

```
@echo off
cls
for /r D:\ %%a in (*) do if "%%~nxa"=="new.txt" set p=%%~dpnxa
if defined p (
echo File found its path - %p%
pause
) else (
echo File not found !
pause
)
```

it will search for the file named `new.txt` on whole drive `D:` folders and sub folders as a final result, it shows the full path of that file `new.txt` as an output like below, (lets assume `new.txt` file in `D:\folder\` )

```
File found and its path - D:\folder\new.txt
Press any key to continue . . .
```

But the problem is , if there is multiple file with same name `new.txt` in drive `D:` on different folder or sub folder , it only shows one path output.

My need is, want to show all files path with the same name `new.txt` on drive `D:` like below output,

**Expected Output** need like this,

```
Files found : 4
Files Paths : 
1 - D:\folder\new.txt
2 - D:\new folder\new.txt
3 - D:\files\new.txt
4 - D:\folder\new\new.txt
```

pls help..Thx in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### I want to show all files path with the same name `new.txt` on drive `D:`

> Expected Output:
>
> ```
> Files found : 4
> Files Paths : 
> 1 - D:\folder\new.txt
> 2 - D:\new folder\new.txt
> 3 - D:\files\new.txt
> 4 - D:\folder\new\new.txt
> ```

Use the following batch file:

```dos
@echo off

setlocal

rem change to the correct directory
cd /d d:\

rem count the files
dir /b new.txt /s 2> nul | find "" /v /c > %temp%\count
set /p _count=<%temp%\count

rem cleanup
del %temp%\count

rem output the number of files
echo Files found : %_count%

rem list the files
echo Files Paths :
dir /b new.txt /s

endlocal
```

---

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [del](http://ss64.com/nt/del.html) - Delete one or more files.
- [dir](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) - Display a list of files and subfolders.
- [endlocal](http://ss64.com/nt/endlocal.html) - End localisation of environment changes in a batch file. Pass variables from one batch file to another.
- [find](http://ss64.com/nt/find.html) - Search for a text string in a file & display all the lines where it is found.
- [set](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) - Display, set, or remove CMD environment variables. Changes made with SET will remain only for the duration of the current CMD session.
- [setlocal](http://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html) - Set options to control the visibility of environment variables in a batch file.